# How to pass parameter to URL based Data Source - Birt 4.3.2

Tags: xml, eclipse, excel, report, birt

I'm looking for advice how to pass parameter to URL based Data Source of type 'excel' - available in Birt 4.3.2

I found an acrticle about "Parameter Driven XML Data Source URL" `http://developer.actuate.com/community/devshare/_/designing-birt-reports/533-parameter-driven-xml-data-source-url` 
but still cannot figure out how to pass my 2 parameters bellow to the Data Source URL?

My Data Source URL of type 'excel' is: 
`http://10.0.0.21:8080/plugins/servlet/tempo-getWorklog/?dateFrom=2014-01-01&dateTo=2014-03-21&format=excel&diffOnly=false&tempoApiToken=3934834-964b-4ada-aa97-4c51e921834`

[Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRbGB.png)

I have defined two date type parameters: from_date and to_date

[Edit Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fvce.png)

The only obsticle left is to figure out how to change "?dateFrom=2014-01-01&dateTo=2014-03-21" with the my newly defined parameters from_date and to_date ?

-- can't post screen shot for parameters screen in the data source due to missing reputation restriction --

According mentioned article the key is using "property binding" tha should looks like in this case like: params["from_date"].value and  params["to_date"].value

how the date set definition looks like in final xml file:

> ```
> <data-sources>
>     <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.excel" name="Data Source" id="7">
>         <property name="URI">http://10.0.0.21:8080/plugins/servlet/tempo-getWorklog/?dateFrom='2014-01-01'&amp;dateTo='2014-03-21'&amp;format=excel&amp;diffOnly=false&amp;tempoApiToken=3ef0eb8b-964b-4ada-aa97-4c51e9fb5333</property>
>         <property name="INCLCOLUMNNAME">yes</property>
>         <property name="INCLTYPELINE">no</property>
>     </oda-data-source>
> </data-sources>
> ```

but can't figure out where to define and how to substitute these in my Data Source URL

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `URI` of your Data Source in the Property Binding register.

Provide a Function for the String where you insert the values of your Parameters:

[image]